# QGIS plugin with additional Button and function

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7

I will want to create a simple QGIS plugin where the user put a number (line_edit) and if that number is something the user take back three new codes(lineEdit_2,lineEdit_3,lineEdit_4) and if user press ok(buttonBox)  then plugin do something else in the some GUI.

For that I create a new additional pushButton in Qdesigner and I create additional def function(run1) for execute code for pushButton.

First I add new pushbutton in `__init__` :

```
def __init__(self, iface):
    self.dlg = pluginDialog()
    self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run1)
```

My gui:

[![qdesigner][1]][1]

Plugin work without error but don't show me the codes (lineEdit_2,lineEdit_3,lineEdit_4) in the plugin window if I press pushbutton,any idea ?

My python code :

```
def run1(self):
    distance = str(self.dlg.lineEdit.text())
    if distance==0:
        area1='some'
        area2='hello'
        area3='world'
    self.dlg.lineEdit_2.setText(str(area1))
    self.dlg.lineEdit_3.setText(str(area2))
    self.dlg.lineEdit_4.setText(str(area3))



def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # Do something else
        pass
```

And I try to replace run1 with:

```
def run1(self):
    self.dlg.show()
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    if result:
        distance = str(self.dlg.lineEdit.text())
        if distance==0:
            area1='some'
            area2='hello'
            area3='world'
        self.dlg.lineEdit_2.setText(str(area1))
        self.dlg.lineEdit_3.setText(str(area2))
        self.dlg.lineEdit_4.setText(str(area3))
        pass
```

but no change.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTMMZ.jpg

Comment: There are some errors in the first version. You get distance from a line edit widget as a string and later you compare it with a number (0). So the if block will never be executed. Also the variables area1 and so on do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Along with the other comments and @Joseph answer you will need to put the button event statements in the initGui(self) function so he click event may be listened to properly:

```
def initGui(self):
  self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few lines in your `run1()` function which you do not need. You also need to set your `if` statement to match a string. Try something like the following:

```
def run1(self):
    distance = str(self.dlg.lineEdit.text())
    if distance == '0':
        area1 = 'some'
        area2 = 'hello'
        area3 = 'world'
        self.dlg.lineEdit_2.setText(str(area1))
        self.dlg.lineEdit_3.setText(str(area2))
        self.dlg.lineEdit_4.setText(str(area3))
    else:
        pass
```

---

Example:

[image: Result]

Comment: you are right now work fine thx @Joseph  the `self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run1)` must be below in` initGui` else not working

Comment: @Mar - Most welcome, glad it worked! Yes, I just noticed artwork21's answer. I suggest you upvote and accept his answer by clicking the green-faded tick next to his answer to show that your problem has been solved :)

Comment: one more question @Joseph,now i want to clear line edit after the running i put all clears edits in the `def ... run :` but if the user use only the pushbutton and then push cancel the next opening plugin have not clear how to fix that  ?because if i use clears on def run1 then or dont show me again nothing or i have errors....Good job joseph you are a very significant in stack overflow

Comment: @Mar - So if the user clicks either _OK_ or _Cancel_, you want the line edits to be cleared?

Comment: yes i want every to start again plugin all line edits have clear

Comment: @Mar - Just put `self.dlg.lineEdit.clear()`, `self.dlg.lineEdit_2.clear()` etc inside your `run(self)` function before or after the `self.dlg.show()` line.

Comment: i do that before,but if i run run1 with the additional button and for finaly i put cancel and not ok then if i run again  the plugin show me the taxt again if i press ok then work the clear

Comment: @Mar - The _OK_ and _Cancel_ buttons are in the `run()` function, you need to clear the line edits here, not in `run1()`.

Comment: i do that but now work clear if i press cancel

Comment: @Mar - It would be better to ask a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and describe _exactly_ what you are looking for. You also asked several questions without accepting a solution (clicking the faded green tick next to answers), this makes it difficult for others to know if your problem has been solved.